# parse the filename with javascript

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

Hello I am an information systems student who is taking a web based apps class and i have a question.  I have an assignment that requires me to take an input with various kinds of characters like "ABC123_DEF456_1.jpg" and requires that the output be displayed as :
ABC
123
ABC
123
a
jpg
and I am stuck.  I have some coding experience but not in javascript.  I have the code

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var str = "ABC123_ABC123_1.jpg";
    var res = str.split(/_/);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
}
</script>
```

but cannot get the correct output.  How do I seperate the other information, and add my 
 tag?  Just a hint? Btw, Ive looked at hours worth of tut's and it didn't help, I now know more about delimiters and such but am stuck here.

Comment: "ABC123_DEF456_1.jpg" > "ABC 123 ABC 123 a jpg"?

Comment: You're using regex expressions to split the string, you should look at using regex to replace the `_` and `.` characters instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost, but this should do the trick.

```
var res = str.replace(/_/g, " ");
```

I created a sample of how the code should work with [jQuery here](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/Yccu7/)